# How to access a variable defined in a react component from another js file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to access a variable defined in a react component from another js file?

I have a react component like follows:

#### App.js

```
class App extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.name = "Rajkiran";
    }
}
```

I have a utils file like below

#### utils.js

```
export fun1() {
    //I want to access the "name"  value defined in App.js here
}
export fun2() {

}
```

Comment: You should create an instance of App class to access it

Comment: You should pass it in as an argument `fun1(this.name)`. There's ways to get around it, but if your function depends on it, its a good practice to make that clear by requiring it as a parameter.

Comment: Hi @MaksimTikhonov, Could you please explain a little bit more clearly? using the above sample code please.

Comment: You could make it a static property, then it would be App.name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the name to the function argument. And when you call the **fun1** pass `this.name` to function.

```
export fun1(name){
    //I want to access the "name"  value defined in App.js here
}

// somewhere in App.js
fun1(this.name)
```

Comment: @Dr.RajkiranJogu can you show this file, where call function?